# Multiplicity of the adjoint of a Lie algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra (not necessarily semisimple!) and $A$ its adjoint. Consider the Clebsch–Gordan series of $A$: $A\otimes A=1+A+\dots$. Is it possible at all that instead, say, $A\otimes A=1+2A+\dots$? My instinct says no — if this is correct, is there a generalization of Lie algebras (more that one seems to exist?!) where it is possible?

Comment: In the non-semisimple case (and even in the non-simple semisimple case) I have no idea how to make sense of the question, which seems to ask about the multiplicity of $A$ in $A\otimes A$— which makes sense if $A$ is irreducible, i.e., if $A$ is simple.

Comment: What is the adjoint of an arbitrary Lie algebra.  Maybe it's a standard term, but I only know it for reductive Lie *groups* (where the result is automatically semisimple).

Comment: @LSpice - the adjoint representation of any Lie algebra is of course always well defined: each element $x$ acts by $[x,-]$. But simplicity and semisimplicity do indeed create problems if one wishes to interpret the equation written here.

Comment: @YCor: So for the non-semisimple case, $A\otimes A$ makes no sense, or reducing to $A$ on the RHS makes no sense (as $A$ isn't irreducible in the first place)? I ask because things like $E7_{1/2}$ where $99\otimes 99$ AFAIK reduces without problems.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431928/multiplicity-of-the-adjoint-of-a-lie-algebra#comment1111769_431928), I didn't mean it wasn't well defined, only that I didn't know the term.  So I guess it is the image of $\operatorname{ad}$ (which makes perfect sense, but can differ from the Lie algebra of an adjoint group in positive characteristic).

Comment: @LSpice ah ok, for me "adjoint" in the Lie context means, first and foremost, the adjoint representation!

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko: Indeed, I mean the adjoint representation (and I didn't even know it doesn't have to be an irrep...).

Comment: Just to summarize: the adjoint representation is meaningful for an arbitrary Lie algebra; also tensor products are meaningful for any two representations, in particular $A\otimes A$ makes sense. But, for an arbitrary Lie algebra, the adjoint representation is irreducible iff the Lie algebra is simple (this is straightforward from the definition). So, asking about the multiplicity makes sense only in this case, and maybe assuming things are well-behaved, so, say, for a finite-dimensional simple Lie algebra in char. zero.

Comment: @YCor: I was tacitly (bad idea in math) assuming finite-dimensional Lie algebras over the complex numbers. Maybe I should ask a question about reps vs. irreps first...

Comment: Let $L=sl(3)$ over the complex numbers. Then $A\otimes A$ contains $A$ with multiplicity 2.

Comment: @VictorOstrik: Feel free to upgrade this to an answer, since it completely shoots down my assumption. (Also feel free to include the clebsch - $8\otimes 8=1+8+8+whatelse?$)